# Exception while taking backup in couchbase using cbbackup

Tags: couchbase

When I'm  trying to take data backup from couchbase VM using the below command

cbbackup -v http://**.**.**.**:8091 /opt/couchbase/backup -u Administrator -p ******. I'm getting the below error.

```
2018-10-22 07:13:01,647: mt cbbackup...
2018-10-22 07:13:01,648: mt source : http://**.***.**.***:8091
2018-10-22 07:13:01,648: mt sink : /opt/couchbase/backup
2018-10-22 07:13:01,648: mt opts : {'username': '<xxx>', 'verbose': 1, 'extra':

{'max_retry': 10.0, 'rehash': 0.0, 'dcp_consumer_queue_length': 1000.0, 'data_only': 0.0, 'uncompress': 0.0, 'nmv_retry': 1.0, 'conflict_resolve': 1.0, 'cbb_max_mb': 100000.0, 'report': 5.0, 'mcd_compatible': 1.0, 'try_xwm': 1.0, 'backoff_cap': 10.0, 'batch_max_bytes': 400000.0, 'report_full': 2000.0, 'flow_control': 1.0, 'batch_max_size': 1000.0, 'seqno': 0.0, 'design_doc_only': 0.0, 'allow_recovery_vb_remap': 0.0, 'recv_min_bytes': 4096.0}
, 'collection': None, 'ssl': False, 'threads': 4, 'key': None, 'password': '<xxx>', 'id': None, 'bucket_source': None, 'silent': False, 'dry_run': False, 'single_node': False, 'vbucket_list': None, 'separator': '::', 'mode': 'diff'}
2018-10-22 07:13:01,655: mt Starting new HTTP connection (1): *********
2018-10-22 07:13:01,662: mt bucket: sample_bucket
Exception in thread s3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
self._target(*self.args, **self._kwargs)
File "/opt/couchbase/lib/python/pump_bfd.py", line 646, in run
return self.future_done(future, rv)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'future' referenced before assignment
```

I'm using couchbase EE 5.1.1

I'm getting the above error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use cbbackupmgr instead for EE

Comment: you're right. I figured it out via documentation later. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reading the documentation and found out for Enterprise edition there's backup manger "cbbackupmgr" which is faster more efficient than cbbackup and cbrestore.
All it requires is to first configure an empty directory as backup directory. For more information pls read the link below.https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/backup-restore/cbbackupmgr-tutorial.html